# Cannot disabled rotation on iPad

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, rotation, ios9

The App has been released to public for months without any problem. But recently I found it can rotate screen on iPad when running iOS 9 or later. And it works without such problem on iPhone.

Is it a bug of iOS 9? or I make something wrong?

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you choose the "Devices" is "iPad", and what is "Device Orientation" show up?

Comment: @anhtu Wow, you're right! The problem solved. It's been working good on iOS 8, so I thought it as a correct setting ;-( . Can you post the answer in "Answer Your Question" so that I can accept it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the **Devices** is **Universal**, it doesn't show the **Orientation** for both **iPhone** and **iPad**.

You should choose **Devices** is **iPad**, and set up **Device Orientation**.